# Iterate JSON with Ruby and insert to MySQL db

Tags: mysql, ruby, arrays, json, parsing

I'm acceessing an open JSON API like this

```
require 'net/http'
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'
require 'uri'
require 'pp'

url = "http://api.turfgame.com/v4/users"
uri = URI.parse(url)

data = [{"name" => "tbone"}]


headers = {"Content-Type" => "application/json"}

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)

response = http.post(uri.path,data.to_json,headers)
```

This gives a JSON ouput like this

```
[{"region"=>{"id"=>141, "name"=>"Stockholm"}, "medals"=>[34, 53, 12, 5, 46], "pointsPerHour"=>95, "blocktime"=>24, "zones"=>[275, 42460, 35956, 31926, 24247, 31722, 1097, 26104, 6072, 24283, 289, 325, 22199, 37740, 22198, 37743, 37074, 22845, 22201, 22846, 7477, 7310], "country"=>"se", "id"=>95195, "rank"=>24, "name"=>"tbone", "uniqueZonesTaken"=>178, "taken"=>1170, "points"=>41693, "place"=>377, "totalPoints"=>176654}]
```

What I want to do is to grab some of the tags:

- name (not in the region block but "tbone")
- blocktime
- totalPoints
- all the IDs from the zone-array

and insert into a mysql table. But I don't get how to iterate the JSON object and get the stuff I want.

doing

```
puts data["name"]
```

gives an error like

```
./headerTest.rb:28:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
        from ./headerTest.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

And I get that it's because there's two name tags but at different depth but i don't get how to accees either one specifically.

Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have:

```
result = [{"region"=>{"id"=>141, "name"=>"Stockholm"}, "medals"=>[34, 53, 12, 5, 46], "pointsPerHour"=>95, "blocktime"=>24, "zones"=>[275, 42460, 35956, 31926, 24247, 31722, 1097, 26104, 6072, 24283, 289, 325, 22199, 37740, 22198, 37743, 37074, 22845, 22201, 22846, 7477, 7310], "country"=>"se", "id"=>95195, "rank"=>24, "name"=>"tbone", "uniqueZonesTaken"=>178, "taken"=>1170, "points"=>41693, "place"=>377, "totalPoints"=>176654}]
```

This is an array with one value. To obtain those values you desire do:

```
result[0].slice("name", "blocktime", "totalPoints", "zones")

# this returns =>  {"name"=>"tbone", "blocktime"=>24, "totalPoints"=>176654, "zones"=>[275, 42460, 35956, 31926, 24247, 31722, 1097, 26104, 6072, 24283, 289, 325, 22199, 37740, 22198, 37743, 37074, 22845, 22201, 22846, 7477, 7310]}
```

Comment: thanks.. didn't work for me though. Did this
`result = JSON.parse(response.body)
result[0].slice("name", "blocktime", "totalPoints", "zones")`

But get this error
``<main>': undefined method `slice' for #<Hash:0x000000011cfd80> (NoMethodError)
`

Comment: ah, no worries. I'm quitting ruby. heading back to the safe old world of php :D